# Where can I find a list of business which accept Bitcoin?

Tags: services, merchants, local

I'm looking for business which accept Bitcoin, both online and in my community. Where can I find a list of these? Are there any community-maintained places which enumerate businesses which accept Bitcoin?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade

Answer (score 0):

[Black and Yellow Pages](https://blackandyellowpages.com/) and [Agorist Marketplace](http://www.agoristmarketplace.com/) both have people who sell services in bitcoin, though there are some people on those sites who prefer to deal in gold or silver.